# React-Player media conrols are not working at smaller width like 100px for react .js

Tags: reactjs

import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

function Video(){
return (

```
    )

}
```

export default Video

Comment: can you format well your code and put the content of the function?

Comment: import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'


const Video = () =>{
    return (
 <div>
 <ReactPlayer controls playing ="true" height = "200px" width ="300px" url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
 
 </div>

  )

 }

export default Video

Comment: This was the function which i have pasted above.